# How do you create a html scrollable area, that just uses the main browser scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I was looking at an issue in JIRA ([e.g. here, an issue in JIRA 4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1190)) and I noticed JIRA 4 has some interesting scrolling behaviour, where when scrolling down with the main browser scrollbar,the jira header scrolls up out of way, then the issue title stays fixed at top, then the rest of the issue continues to scroll. So the issue title is always visible.

There isn't an extra vertical scrollbar. Its all scrolled via the main browser scrollbar. So its either css or javascript magic! Any idea how they do that?

Cheers,

Phil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It changes dynamically the div `#stalker` which has `position:absolute;top:76px;`. When the user scroll, change the position to `position:fixed;top:0` and keep it in a fixed place, giving you the ability to scroll the rest content.

---

*Edit*

I created an example of this behavoir, because I was curious and here the demo if you want to check it http://jsbin.com/igiji5/3

Comment: Thanks Sotris for the answer and demo.

Answer (score 4):

Atlassian published the source of the Javascript at http://docs.atlassian.com/aui/3.0/jquery.stalker.js.html

Answer (score 0):

That is created using JavaScript.

I can see by using FireBug to inspect the div#stalker that it changes class and style attributes when you are scrolling.